# What is equivalent of Winform Control.Handle in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

As titled.

I want register my Silverlight application as Clipboard Viewer, so it needs my control handle.

I have been searching in msdn and google and doesn't find anything.  Does it even exists?

Comment: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/clipboard

Comment: @HansPassant The reason I want to use Clipboard Viewer is because I will need to monitor other data object in clipboard(i.e image etc), which is not supported by SL.

Comment: Don't use Silverlight to get a Winforms job done.  I suppose you could write a COM server to make Silverlight capable.  That can still only work OOB.

Answer (score 0):

The control handle is an HWND, a handle to a window, as far as I remember there are no windows in SL. If for instance you were under WPF, there is the WindowInteropHelper class that just does that.

Regarding SL, a search brings the following :
[SilverlightContainer.WindowHandle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitest.extension.silverlight.silverlightcontainer.windowhandle.aspx)

Not sure you'll be able to use it however, it's part of the .NET infrastructure.

Comment: ahhh... I see "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."..... I will keep googling...... hope I can find something useful...

Comment: Through reflection and ILSpy you might be able to get access to a non-public member that is the HWND you are looking for.